# Lossy conversion from float64 to uint8

Tags: python, rgb, hsv

Code from *https://www.makeartwithpython.com/blog/visualizing-sort-algorithms-in-python/*

```
from imageio import imsave

import numpy as np

newImage = np.random.randint(0, 255, (300, 300, 3))

in_hsv_h = color.convert_colorspace(newImage, 'RGB', 'HSV')
in_hsv_s = in_hsv_h.copy()
in_hsv_v = in_hsv_h.copy()

for i in range(newImage.shape[0]):
    in_hsv_h[i,:,0] = np.sort(in_hsv_h[i,:,0])
    in_hsv_s[i,:,1] = np.sort(in_hsv_s[i,:,1])
    in_hsv_v[i,:,2] = np.sort(in_hsv_v[i,:,2])

imsave('testing-sorted-hue.png', color.convert_colorspace(in_hsv_h, 'HSV', 'RGB'))
imsave('testing-sorted-saturation.png', color.convert_colorspace(in_hsv_s, 'HSV', 'RGB'))
```

`Lossy conversion from float64 to uint8. Range [0, 1]. Convert image to uint8 prior to saving to suppress this warning.`

Still very inexperienced, any quick way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The warning is self explanatory: `color.convert_colorspace(in_hsv_h, 'HSV', 'RGB')` is of type `float64`, and `imsave`, convert elements to `uint8`.

The pixels of PNG image, are stored as one byte per component (one byte for red, one for green and one for blue).
Each component is an integer value in range [0, 255] (type `uint8`).

The output of color.convert_colorspace is of `float64`, each color component is in range [0, 1] of type `float64` (stored as 64 bits in memory, and much more accurate than `uint8`).

The conversion from `float64` range [0, 1] to `uint8` range [0, 255] is performed like: `uint8_val = round(float64_val*255)`.
The rounding operation loose some data (for example: in case float64_val*255 = 132.658, the result is rounded to 133).

> Convert image to uint8 prior to saving to suppress this warning

Tells you to convert the image elements to `uint8` prior to saving.

Solution is simple.
Multiply by 255, and add `.astype(np.uint8)`.

```
imsave('testing-sorted-hue.png', (color.convert_colorspace(in_hsv_h, 'HSV', 'RGB')*255).astype(np.uint8))
```

In order for your code to work, you should also add `.astype(np.uint8)` when building `newImage`:

```
newImage = np.random.randint(0, 255, (300, 300, 3)).astype(np.uint8)
```

---

Complete code:

```
from imageio import imsave
from skimage import color

import numpy as np

newImage = np.random.randint(0, 255, (300, 300, 3)).astype(np.uint8)


in_hsv_h = color.convert_colorspace(newImage, 'RGB', 'HSV')
in_hsv_s = in_hsv_h.copy()
in_hsv_v = in_hsv_h.copy()

for i in range(newImage.shape[0]):
    in_hsv_h[i,:,0] = np.sort(in_hsv_h[i,:,0])
    in_hsv_s[i,:,1] = np.sort(in_hsv_s[i,:,1])
    in_hsv_v[i,:,2] = np.sort(in_hsv_v[i,:,2])

imsave('testing-sorted-hue.png', (color.convert_colorspace(in_hsv_h, 'HSV', 'RGB')*255).astype(np.uint8))
imsave('testing-sorted-saturation.png', (color.convert_colorspace(in_hsv_s, 'HSV', 'RGB')*255).astype(np.uint8))
```

---

Remark:
The example in [makeartwithpython](https://www.makeartwithpython.com/blog/visualizing-sort-algorithms-in-python/) uses `from imageio import imsave` instead of `from scipy.misc import imsave`, and the example in the site is working correctly.

Note:
I don't have a lot of Python programming experience, please take my answer with some caution.

Comment: As denis_smyslov answer below reminds: Skimage library warns against using astype to change dtype of an image. (https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/data_types.html)

Answer (score 5):

There is no reason to use `imageio` library to save your image, since you already use `skimage.color` module from `skimage` library. You can keep using `skimage` to save the image with `skimage.save`.

Moreover, the warning itself ("Lossy conversion from float64 to uint8. Range [0, 1]. Convert image to uint8 prior to saving to suppress this warning.") comes from `skimage` library.

This warning appears because dtype of the image is changed during saving from original 'float64' to 'uint8'.

`print(color.convert_colorspace(in_hsv_h, 'HSV', 'RGB').dtype)
float64`

But saving an image changes dtype to 'uint8':

`from skimage import io
io.imread('testing-sorted-hue.png').dtype
dtype('uint8')`

To suppress the warning you need to change dtype of the image before saving. Skimage provides utility function [img_as_ubyte](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/data_types.html) to do this:

`in_hsv_h = color.convert_colorspace(in_hsv_h, 'HSV', 'RGB')
print('dtype before:', in_hsv_h.dtype)
dtype before: float64`

`from skimage.util import img_as_ubyte
in_hsv_h=img_as_ubyte(in_hsv_h)
print('dtype after: ', in_hsv_h.dtype)
dtype after:  uint8`

Skimage library warns against using `astype` to change dtype of an image.

Comment: In general, depending on how one generated the float array, you might want to use exposure.rescale_intensity before converting the dtype.